# jquery on click no working on EDIT button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm developing CMS. Issue is that `jquery` on click no working on EDIT Button. Code seems fine to me but I did not understand why it is not working. It is working on Add Button.

JS

```
<script>

    var loading_message = "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'><img src='<?=site_url()?>assets/_admin/images/loading.gif'/></div></div>";

    function list()
    {
        $('#main_contents').html(loading_message);
        var form_data = {
            ajax        : '1',
            actioncall  : 'show_all',
        };
        $.ajax({
            url     : "<?=site_url()?>itadmin/ajaxBanners",
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : form_data,
            success : function(data){
                $('#main_contents').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function add()
    {
        $('#right_block').html(loading_message);
        var form_data = {
            ajax        : '1',
            actioncall  : 'add_form',
        };
        $.ajax({
            url     : "<?=site_url()?>itadmin/ajaxBanners",
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : form_data,
            success : function(data){
                $('#right_block').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        list();
        add();

        $('#addbanner').on('click',function()
        {
            add();
        });

        $('.edit').on('click',function()
        {
            $('#right_block').html(loading_message);
            var id  = this.id;
            alert(id);
            var form_data = {
                ajax            : '1',
                actioncall      : 'edit',
                id              : id,
            };

            $.ajax({
                url     : "<?=site_url()?>itadmin/ajaxBanners",
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : form_data,
                success : function(data){
                    $('#right_block').html(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $('.delete').on('click',function(){
            var id  = this.id;
            alert(id);
        });

        $(document).on('submit','form#process-data',function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var form_data = {
                ajax                : '1',
                link_togo           : $('#link_togo').val(),
                title               : $('#title').val(),
                description         : $('#description').val(),
                keyword             : $('#keyword').val(),
                placement           : $('#placement').val(),
                location            : $('#location').val(),
                status              : $('#switch-size').val(),//#default
                actioncall          : 'add'
            };

            //alert(JSON.stringify(form_data));

            $.ajax({
                url     : "<?=site_url()?>itadmin/ajaxBanners",
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : form_data,
                success : function(data)
                {
                    /*setTimeout(function ()
                    { 
                        $('.img_pre').attr('src',data);
                        $('.delete_btn').show();
                    }, 1000);*/
                    $("#right_block").html(data);
                    list();
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="banner-row1">
    <div class="banner-row-pic">
        <img src="http://localhost/cms-basic/assets/_admin/images/pic.png" alt="pic1" />
    </div>
    <div class="banner-row-text">
        <h2>Latest News</h2>
        <p>Every news is important</p>
        <p class="text-muted">
            <small>
            Keyword: news<br />
            Placement: others<br />
            Location: Homepage<br />
            Link: <a href="http://pakhotline.com">http://pakhotline.com</a>
            </small>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-row-edit">
        <a class="edit" id="2" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="http://localhost/cms-basic/assets/_admin/images/edit.png" />
        </a>
        <a class="delete" id="2" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="http://localhost/cms-basic/assets/_admin/images/delet.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>


<div class="banner-row1">
    <div class="banner-row-pic">
        <img src="http://localhost/cms-basic/assets/_admin/images/pic.png" alt="pic1" />
    </div>
    <div class="banner-row-text">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>description</p>
        <p class="text-muted">
            <small>
            Keyword: keyword<br />
            Placement: Bottom<br />
            Location: static_page<br />
            Link: <a href="link">link</a>
            </small>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-row-edit">
        <a class="edit" id="1" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="http://localhost/cms-basic/assets/_admin/images/edit.png" />
        </a>
        <a class="delete" id="1" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="http://localhost/cms-basic/assets/_admin/images/delet.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

**Note**: - I'm using jQuery `1.11.3`

Comment: same ids......................................

Comment: Only provide us the code that doesn't work. And make a Fiddle.

Comment: You have duplicate id's in your page - that will not work as you expect. Make sure all id's are unique.

Comment: I have two banners on list. Each banner code start from `<div class="banner-row1">` and I also have mentioned `var id  = this.id;` in onClick does it not OK?

Comment: Not if it creates a duplicate id and each banner has the *same* id.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How can I solve this duplication issue. Could you please write a solution?

Comment: You have to iterate your id values or not use them at all. You're asking for an answer to what is now a different question. If you want to do that post another question showing the code which creates your id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because of same ids.

Replace

```
$('.edit').on('click',function()
```

with

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use an ID once, since it has to be [unique](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: I have two class for each banner. `edit` and 2nd is `delete`

Comment: Can you mention where I use ID twice which is happening issue?

Comment: @Hassaan you have two things with `id="1"` and two things with `id="2"`. You *must* use unique id's.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have two banners on list. Each banner code start from `<div class="banner-row1">` and I also have mentioned `var id  = this.id;` in onClick does it not OK?